# XCode 6 no distribute button in archive oraginzer

Tags: xcode6

I want to distribute my app to a tester. According to the App Distribution Guide once I've created an archive I click "distribute" which is under "Validate". This button doesn't exist. I see instead "Submit" and "Export" What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click Export. It's the new distribute :)

EDIT: Distribute -button has been replaced with Export -button in XCode 6. When you click Export you will have almost the same options as you had with Distribute.